# Properly route to server-containing gems proxied as directories in nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, nginx, thin

I have several applications running on different ports of a development server and use nginx as a reverse proxy.

Some of these apps are Rails applications and some are gems that come packaged with a preconfigured server (e.g. mailcatcher, gollum, sinatra). I can't find a configuration to set the proper paths for static assets.

Consider a request made to http://oh.no/gem which serves content from http://oh.no:666
Since the gem points to files at the root of the site  (e.g. '/images/wth.jpg') they never load.  With Rails apps, I generally change the root directive in nginx and appropriately configure the apps files, but that method lacks elegance and is a PITA when toying with gems.

With Rails applications, I'm familiar with [adding directives to allow Passenger to handle a sub-URI elegantly](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri), but I don't know a noninstrusive solution for apps loaded by other servers. What additions/deletions would I need to make to the following to serve the assets?

```
location /gem {
  proxy_pass          http://localhost:666/;
  proxy_redirect      default;
  proxy_set_header    Host                  $host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP             $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host      $host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server    $host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For       $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```